# The type of one of the expressions in the join clause is incorrect. Type inference failed in the call to 'GroupJoin'

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq

I'm trying to left join multiple tables in linqtoentities with multiple conditionals, but am unable to get it to operate on even two tables. The error is 'The type of one of the expressions in the join clause is incorrect.' and the code is:

```
var listToSend = from row in meetingEmails
                 join s in sentEmail on new {a = (int) row.StaffID, b = (int) row.MeetingID} equals new {a = (int) s.SentToUserID, b = (int) s.CaseID}
```

All four columns contained in the comparison types are non-nullable ints (the name and type declaration was an attempt to solve this) so i'm struggling to understand why its having trouble with the types.

The only difference I can see is that the right half is straight from the database, the left is run through a previous query with only certain fields output, though I don't think this would have an effect since the datatypes of the fields in the join criteria are still being recognised consistently by the compiler (as ints).

Despite finding lots of reports of this error I couldn't find any posts that provide the insight I need for this so any help would be appreciated

Comment: Try replace int with int? which will allow nulls.

Comment: Have you tried doing this without creating anonymously typed objects?  Such as `(int)row.StaffID equals (int)s.SentToUserID && (int)row.MeetingID equals (int)s.CaseID`

Comment: please post your actual query. You mentioned about `GroupJoin` but there is not any group join here. It's just an inner join (or normal Join).

Comment: @jdweng - It doesnt work, though I dont want it to allow nulls anyway

Comment: @Michael McGriff - i have, that's the way I tried intially but I cant structure it like that as once you hit the first equals the left hand table falls out of scope.

Comment: @King King - that is the actual query, its just the error message was from an earlier version of the code, and since the only difference is the word groupjoin changed to join I didn't notice. the only changes between it as it is now and the earlier version is the following line added to the end:
into joinedrow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Incase anyone else comes across this post and has the same issue, I managed to resolve it.

To make it work I added `select new { row.MeetingID, s.EmailLogID };` on the end.

I'm not sure why not having finished writing the query yet made the compiler think it was a datatype error rather than the usual 'A query body must end with a select clause or a group clause' though and would like to know why.